# Are there any libraries to manage json content in a database field of a rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I have a rails 2 app that manages a json field within a table. It needs to:

- Read the json
- Convert the json to model attributes and form fields
- Save edits to the form fields into the json field
- Add validation for some of the json values
- Be applicable to multiple models

Currently, I have a library file that manually adds methods to extract and save into the json, like so:

```
module Configuration
  def configuration_json
    configuration? ? JSON.parse(self.configuration) : {}
  end

  def some_json_value
    if !self.configuration.nil? && configuration_json["parentKey"]
      configuration_json["parentKey"]["someJsonValue"]
    end
  end

  def some_json_value=(val)
    new_config = configuration_json.deep_merge({
      "FeatureConfiguration" => { "someJsonValue" => val }
    })
    self.configuration = new_config.to_json
  end

  def some_json_value_validation
    # ...
  end
end
```

And in the models I include this

```
class SomeModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Configuration
  validate :some_json_value_validation

  # ...
end
```

Is there a better/DRY-er way? Currently it's really clunky when the json structure changes, as there are quite a few steps to modify in the rails app.

I can't change the use of the json field, as it's for configuration of another application, which is the main application that the rails app supports.

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to make a Configuration model, and simply make a `to_json` method that builds the correct json object.

If you really want to parse the json and convert it back on every operation, you could make a helper to create the methods for you, like `json_attr_accessor`

Example:

```
module Configuration

  def configuration_json
    configuration.present? ? JSON.parse(configuration) : {}
  end

  module ModelExtensions

    def json_attr_accessor(*symbols)
      symbols.each do |sym|

        key = sym.to_s.camelize(:lower)

        define_method(sym) do
          ['FC', key].reduce(configuration_json) do |json, key|
            json and json[key]
          end
        end

        define_method("#{sym}=") do |val|
          hash = configuration_json.deep_merge 'FC' => { key => val }
          self.configuration = hash.to_json
        end

      end
    end

  end

  def self.included(base)
    base.extend ModelExtensions
  end

end
```

And in the model:

```
class SomeModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Configuration
  json_attr_accessor :some_json_value
end
```

Here's a link to help for custom validators:

http://www.perfectline.ee/blog/building-ruby-on-rails-3-custom-validators

Comment: The problem is that the json mapping is not that generic. Some map to 1st level keys, and some are 2nd level keys with another required key when it is present. Basically custom mapping logic for each value. So, I want to wrap up this custom logic in easy to use accessor methods.

Comment: Actually, this could be what I need. The mapping doesn't need to be as custom anymore. Will try it out when I get a chance.